Two definitions of separability?
I am confused if the following two definitions have anything to do with each other:
In analysis IV we have seen that a space $X$ is called separable if it has a subset which is countable and dense, i.e. there exists a subset $D=\{x_n\}_n \in X$ of elements of the space such that every open subset of the space contains at least one element from the sequence.
In topology, a space $X$ is called separated, Hausdorff or $T_2$ if for any two points $x, y \in X$ there are open neighborhoods $U_x, U_y$ respectively such that the intersection of $U_x, U_y$ is empty.
I do not understand how these definitions are related to each other:
Let $X$ separable, $x\neq y\in X$ points and take open nbhds $U_x, U_y$ resp. then both $U_x, U_y$ contain some points of $D$. I cannot prove $X$ to be $T_2$ with these informations...?
Are these definitions even related or am I making something up completely?

No, separability has nothing to do with the various separation axioms. It wasn't the best choice of terminology, but that's the way the cookie crumbles.
